# How recovery Cassandra from deserializing mutation error:

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I have a single cassandra, now this error appears when I start the server:

```
ERROR 11:18:45 Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReadHandler$CommitLogReadException: Unexpected error deserializing mutation; saved to /tmp/mutation4787806670239768067dat.  This may be caused by replaying a mutation against a table with the same name but incompatible schema.  Exception follows: org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MarshalException: A local deletion time should not be negative
```

If I delete all the commitlog and saved_cached files the server goes up, but the next day when I reboot the cassandra, the error occurs again.

What's wrong? How to make cassandra stable again?

I use cassandra 3.9, but I tried to upgrade to 3.11 and nothing has changed.

Comment: `A local deletion time should not be negative` Is there large TTLs or deletes in your application? Why are you rebooting cassandra (unrelated question)?

Comment: Because I use the same server to cassandra and tomcat, I reboot all system 1x day.  In my application I use TTL > 5 minutes.

Comment: should open a jira at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA/ including your /tmp/mutation4787806670239768067dat

Comment: Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-14914?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel